# Creating a web server with Flask that outputs something available for a GET request

Tags: python, http, heroku, flask

I have a Python script that outputs a piece of text in a string. I am attempting to make that piece of text available online so that I can pull it down to an Arduino Microcontroller. In other words, the work flow goes like this: Text source > Python > ??? > Arduino > Final output.

I've used the sample Flask code from Heroku to begin to experiment with getting this functionality working. Their code for Flask follows:

```
 import os

 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
 def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

When I attempt to do an HTTP get request on my heroku app, it gives me a 404. I suspect this is because this script doesn't really output anything. For example, when I use this Processing app from the Processing.org website to do a GET request:

```
import processing.net.*;

Client c;
String data;

void setup() {
   size(200, 200);
   background(50);
   fill(200);
   c = new Client(this, "http://freezing-stream-5123.herokuapp.com/", 80); // Connect to server on port 80
   c.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\n"); // Use the HTTP "GET" command to ask for a Web page
   c.write("Host: my_domain_name.com\n\n"); // Be polite and say who we are
   }

void draw() {
   if (c.available() > 0) { // If there's incoming data from the client...
   data = c.readString(); // ...then grab it and print it
   println(data);
  }
}
```

What is returned is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 22:27:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 968
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><meta http-     equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://earthlink-help.com/main?
InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=xj6e3468k634hy3945zg3zkhfn7zfgf6&FailureMode    =1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fmy_domain_name.com%2F&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0"/><script type="text/javascript">url="http://earthlink-help.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=xj6e3468k634hy3945zg3zkhfn7zfgf6&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fmy_domain_name.com%2F&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0";if(top.location!=location){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&h="+y;}window.
location.replace(url);</script></head><body></body></html>
```

AKA: Nothing is there. "Hello world" does show up when I use curl to pull the webpage, but I don't know if that means anything.

So my question is: can anyone point me towards something that will stick my string in something that I can retrieve it from? I realize this is probably a stupid question, but I'm totally lost in a sea of web servers etc and would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "Hello world" does show up when I use curl to pull the webpage, but I don't know if that means anything.

It probably means it's working and the problem is possibly in the Processing code.

It's not very clear if your problem is just with getting the basic Flask app running.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of the problem is that you are not returning a response object, look at the API docs. There is a Response object that you should be able to just fill with text, either json or just text. If you plan on using the URL endpoint look at using the function 'jsonify' from Flask.